# How to fix 'Element not found' when adding watermark by vb.net (64-bit Windows & 64-bit Office)?

Tags: ms-word, office-interop, vb.net-2010, watermark

I want add a text watermark in word.

I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 15.
The same code works for office 2016 32-bit, but for office 365 64-bit, will
throw the exception 'Element not found' 0x8002802B when I call ".AddTextEffect".
How can I fix this problem?

```
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(file.FullName)
wordApp.Visible = True
'Create watermark
With wordDoc
    .Activate()
    .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddTextEffect(
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, 
        watermark, font, 1,
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0)
End With
```

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't work but... Comment out the first two lines following `With wordDoc` then see if the following line of code works (or at least gives a different error) in place of the line throwing the error: `wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.AddTextEffect(
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, 
        watermark, font, 1,
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot say this is VB.Net Code, I will try that can run for VBA, but not for VB.net.

Comment: Your comment is unclear. Did you try the syntax I posted in my comment?

Comment: I tried. But still throw the same exception.

Comment: FWIW I can't replicate the problem. The method appears to be part of the PIAs installed with Office 365 64-bit...